# selenium webdriver find element by 'href' not working using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating a page Object model using selenium web driver and trying to link an element which has a 'href'. By creating in this way

`[element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("signin")).click();]`

I am getting an error like

> cannot covert from void to web element.

Can anyone can help me with this

Comment: stack trace is always welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First select element in browser, and copy it's selector(inspect -> copy selector). Then use it as cssSelector. Try not to use link text coz it is language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

hi you are getting above error because

```
element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("signin")).click();

you are trying to perform action (i.e click) and its object identification (element =...)
together whic h is not correct to make it work plz do it like below 
element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("signin"));
element .click();
```

Also why are you getting the error **"cannot covert from void to web element"** `cause the type of .click() is void for more information please look at official documentation`http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html
now it will stop giving you error hope this helps you